# What is intellj trying to tell me with this error

Tags: kotlin

i know some intermediate Java, but i wanted to start learning kotlin

i want to use intellj or android studio but they both show the same error...

Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\triim\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init3.gradle' (C:\Users\triim.gradle\caches\7.1\scripts\a3km84diab7o92uj57csy2v6x).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  **

Comment: *Unsupported class file major version 61* is an issue with the version of Java you're using. It means you're running byte code compiled with JDK17 with a JRE that's of a lower version